# Two wire thermostat

Tags: wiring

Can I use an add a wire on a two wire thermostat system the thermostat is a white Rodgers and I would like to run the furnace fan for ventilation

Comment: What prevents you from running new thermostat cable? Also, can you link to this "add a wire" gadget you're using?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, as long as you can get an additional wire to the stat location, you can now operate the blower fan independantly.  This is with the understanding that the stat has the capability and the furnace is ready for this capability.

Comment: This doesn't really say... Anything... More of a truism.